# How do i use the sendgrid API with symfony 4

Tags: symfony4, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I need help to embed sendgrid in my symfony 4 project.
I installed the https://github.com/expertcoder/SwiftmailerSendGridBundle to use the api, correctly followed the instructions, got an API key from sendgrid

Here's the part in my .env file

```
MAILER_URL=smtp://smtp.sendgrid.net:587?encryption=tls&auth_mode=login&username=%SENDGRID_API_KEY%&password=%SENDGRID_API_KEY%
###> expertcoder/swiftmailer-send-grid-bundle ###
SENDGRID_API_KEY= MyAPiKey
###< expertcoder/swiftmailer-send-grid-bundle ###
```

Is it correct ? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This answer is not using the Swiftmailer but Symfony's new Mailer. Following the [Symfony Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html) you have to install

`composer require symfony/mailer`
and `composer require symfony/sendgrid-mailer`

then uncomment the new lines in the .env file and add your Sendgrid API key

```
###> symfony/sendgrid-mailer ###
SENDGRID_KEY=YOUR-API-KEY
MAILER_DSN=smtp://$SENDGRID_KEY@sendgrid
###< symfony/sendgrid-mailer ###
```

(the MAILER_DSN uses the SENDGRID_KEY variable so do not set it twice)

Ideally you would add these lines to a **.env.local** file as well and remove the API-key from your .env file.

finally:

```
       $email = (new Email())
            ->from('hello@example.com')
            ->to('you@example.com')
            //->cc('cc@example.com')
            //->bcc('bcc@example.com')
            //->replyTo('fabien@example.com')
            //->priority(Email::PRIORITY_HIGH)
            ->subject('Time for Symfony Mailer!')
            ->text('Sending emails is fun again!')
            ->html('<p>See Twig integration for better HTML integration!</p>');

        $mailer->send($email);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string of connection has a problem, in user you must put apikey

Example:

```
MAILER_URL=smtp://smtp.sendgrid.net:587?encryption=tls&auth_mode=login&username=apikey&password=SG.7RafsniRSAa-almQ.DV---------------------fN-9hMkExWhM9RHTVUMj9DE
```